# Why do i get 0 pinned objects when i query LocalDatastore? iOS. Swift. Parse v1.7.5

Tags: ios, swift, local-datastore

```
func queryForPhotosFromLocalDatastore()
{
    var xquery = PFQuery(className: "Follows")
    xquery.fromLocalDatastore()
    //xquery.whereKey("Follower", equalTo: PFUser.currentUser()!.objectId!)
    xquery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects, error) -> Void in
        if let xobjects = objects
        {
            if xobjects.count > 0
            {
                for yobject in xobjects
                {
                    println("Done")
                
                
                }
            }
            else
            {
                println("number of objects is \(xobjects.count)")
            }
        }
        else
        {
            println(error?.userInfo)
        }
    }
}


func queryForPhotosFromParse()
{
        PFObject.unpinAllObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock(nil)
        var xquery = PFQuery(className: "Follows")
        xquery.whereKey("Follower", equalTo: PFUser.currentUser()!.objectId!)
        xquery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects, error) -> Void in
            if let xobjects = objects
            {
                println("xobjects are \(xobjects.count)")
                println("querying from parse")
                for yobject in xobjects
                {
                    var followedUser = yobject["Following"] as! String
                    
                    var query = PFQuery(className: "Images")
                    query.whereKey("userID", equalTo: followedUser)
                    query.orderByDescending("createdAt")
                    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (xobjects, error) -> Void in
                        if let objects = xobjects
                        {
                            PFObject.pinAllInBackground(objects, block: { (success, error) -> Void in
                                if error == nil
                                {
                                    println("Pinned \(objects.count) objects")
                                    self.queryForPhotosFromLocalDatastore()
                                }
                            })
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            println(error?.userInfo)
                        }
                    }
                    
                }
                
                
            }
        }
    
    }
```

// The number of objects its returning (xobjects.count) is 0. Why is that so ?
I tried to have query localdatastore in my app but The number of objects its returning (xobjects.count) is 0. Why is that so ?
i have tried to query before with the previous versions but same thing happened. The latest version on parse says that they have fixed the error but I'm still getting the number of objects retrieved from localdatastore as "0". Please Help.

Comment: Did you happen to find the reason for this? I'm also getting 0 objects out of my query